# Treating both Presbyopia and Myopia with LASIK/laser

Tags: eye, myopia-nearsightedness, lasik, laser

So I suffer from Myopia. The degree is around 5-6. I also suffer from Presbyopia. I am 43 years old.

My doctor, one of the best in my region, says that my presbyopia cannot be corrected with surgery. So I would need glasses anyway.

But I read in some websites that Presbyopia can be corrected by lasik/laser surgery too.

What is the truth? Can both be corrected with lasik or laser? Can both be corrected at the same time through one surgery?